# passing values from richtext box to another in an another Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, user-interface, richtextbox

so im creating a project about a SuperMarket everything is almost done but my problem is with Bill/Cart how can i pass a value from richtextbox to another and how can i add up all the values on different forms to the Bill\Cart Form ?
and here is one of the forms(Vegetables) codes :

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal value = numericUpDown1.Value;
    decimal Total = value * (decimal)0.60;

    decimal value1 = numericUpDown2.Value;
    decimal Total1 = value1 * (decimal)0.90;

    decimal value2 = numericUpDown3.Value;
    decimal Total2 = value2 * (decimal)0.30;

    decimal value3 = numericUpDown4.Value;
    decimal Total3 = value3 * (decimal)0.90;
    richTextBox2.Text = Total + Total1 + Total2 + Total3 + " JD ";
}
```

Comment: lease provide more information on your issue. Such things as what you have tried, what has worked and what has not worked along with any scripts and/or error messages. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: `richTextBox2.Text = (Total + Total1 + Total2 + Total3).ToString("C")` (where `"C"` means *format as Currency*, which will also add the Currency symbol and a number decimal places defined by the current culture - 3 decimal places, if that's Jordanian Dinar). You didn't specify what *pass a value from richtextbox to another* implies.

Comment: Jimi : it kinda hard to explain in here my in english is not that good i apologize but i will try

Comment: is there an email where i can send you the project to see it by yourself ?

Comment: @Jimi give him your email :))

Comment: @YosuefYaser, you can upload your project here in link format, which may let me know your meaning.